# open sets metrics maximum and taxicab

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

hey could someone show me the formula to draw a unit ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with a center at $0$ in the maximum and taxicab metric? I use this site and I cant draw this two sets :( https://www.geogebra.org/graphing

Answer (score 0):

In taxicab metric we have a square bounded by $x+y=1, x-y=1, -x-y=1, -x+y=1$ (the interior of the square is the open unit ball).

For the maximum metric we just have the larger (open) square bounded by $x=1, x=-1, y=1, y=-1$, of course.

Comment: But how to draw this in geogebra or any other site? For example for open set in eucledian norm i have no problem, i write formula $x^2+y^2<1$ and I have my open set. But I have problem with these two other metrics :( I need this to pdf file

Comment: @Piszczu cannot you have a simultaneous system $-1< x+y< 1 , -1 < x-y < 1$ for the first, and $-1 < x < 1, -1 < y < 1$ for the second? worked for me...

Comment: @Piszczu you can have two combined inequalities in the left column in geogebra.

Comment: what is the command? Because I type  $-1< x+y< 1 , -1 < x-y < 1$  and nothing shows up.I am using this tool for the first time and I only need these two drawings

Comment: @Piszczu you put these two on separate lines in the left column.

Comment: What does it mean in the left column? I write {-1<x-y<1},{-1<x+y<1} and still doesnt work

Comment: @Piszczu following the link on a PC I get a left column in which I can type a formula `-1 < x+y < 1` and on the line underneath the same with `x-y` Two shaded areas that intersect in a “diamond” result.

Comment: I understand but I want on the picture only intersect area, without other part. How to do it?